# Validação de Formulário com Submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

No Meu projeto tenho três formularios sendo um independente do outro. O `form1, form2 e form3`. O `form1` consta campos obrigátorios para ser preenchido, sendo que esses dados serão necessarios para gerar as informações dos outros dois `forms`.
Portanto segue o meu problema, como posso fazer para verificar se o `form1` foi preenchido na hora que eu faço o submit pelo `form2 ou form3`? 
Eu consegui tratar isso com `PHP`, na hora que chega na pagina `PHP` eu faço um `isset` no `POST` para ver se os dados do `form1` veio também, só que preciso que esse trabalho seja realizado no lado do cliente.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="FormInfObg" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder='<?php if(isset($_POST['nome'])){$_SESSION['nome']=$_POST["nome"];echo $_SESSION['nome'];}else{ echo "Nome Completo";}?>'>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cargo" placeholder='<?php if(isset($_POST['cargo'])){$_SESSION['cargo']=$_POST["cargo"];echo $_SESSION['cargo'];}else{ echo "Cargo";}?>'>
    <button class="btn btn-default" name="btnSalvar" value="btnSalvar">Salvar <span class="fa fa-floppy-o"></span></button>
</form>

 <form class="form-horizontal" id="Form2" action="proc.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="filial">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="btnSubmitForm2">Enviar</button>
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" id="Form3" action="proc.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nSerial">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="btnSubmitForm3">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, precisa fazer o `POST` dos `FORMs` via `Ajax`, mas para apresentar a melhor forma você precisa postar o conteúdo da sua página na pergunta...

Comment: Pronto, ve se ajuda.

Comment: O primeiro `form` precisa ser salvo antes ou só preenchido e irá salvar de uma vez?

Comment: Precisa ser salvo antes. Para não ter situação de o usuario fazer o `submit` dos outros dois `forms` sem ter preenchido o `form1`

Answer (score 0):

Bom se você tem 2 forms e eles dependem do form1, sugiro que coloque os dados do form1 em hidden fields nos 2 forms...

Imagino que o fluxo seja este...

1° usuário preenche os dados no form1

2° usuário clica *(em algum botão, para salvar no servidor ou para dar continuidade)

3° dependendo dos dados que foram inseridos o usuário é redirecionado para o form2 ou form3

4° os dados do form1 são setados em `<input type="hidden" name="dado_do_form1"/>` via javascript no form que foi redirecionado

5° usuário preenche os dados restantes do form2 ou form3 e envia para servidor

6° servidor verifica os dados recebidos

Se você tiver 2 forms e der submit em 1 deles, os dados do outro form não será enviado.

Comment: Já fiz esse tipo de verificação, quando ele chega na pagina `PHP` verifica se os dados do `form1` foram enviados, se não retorna para o `HTML`. Só que quando ele retorna para o `HTML`, os dados preenchidos somem após o `submit`.

Comment: Se você tiver 2 ou mais forms e der submit em 1 deles os dados dos outros forms não serão enviados.
O que você precisa fazer é no form1 fazer 1 button normal e jogar uma acção no click dele para preencher os dados dos hidde camp no form seguinte.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode validar no evento [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) do formulário, e caso o usuário não tenha preenchido os valores do primeiro, o segundo não será submetido.

```
$("#form2").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();      

  if (!validarForm1())
    alert("Primeiro preencha o primeiro formulário");
  else {
    // post por ajax do segundo formulário
  }

});

$("#form3").submit(function(event) {
 // faca a mesma coisa 
});

function validarForm1(){
    var form1Campo1 = $("#form1Campo1").val(),
        form1Campo2 = $("#form1Campo2").val();

    if (!form1Campo1 || !form1Campo2)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/xyLrx3eg/2/

Comment: Ai eu teria que fazer um evento desse para cada `form`? Por exemplo, `$("#form3").submit(function(event) { ..});` Isso?

Comment: mas eu chamo aonde essa função? No botão ou no formulario? Por exemplo, `<form  onsubmit="return validarForm1()">` ou `<button class="btn btn-default"  onclick="validarForm1()">`

Comment: Eu coloquei ela dentro do evento `submit`, aqui: `if (!validarForm1())`. Note que ali ela está sendo invocada.

Answer (score 0):

> Para não ter situação de o usuário fazer o submit dos outros dois forms sem ter preenchido o form1

### validação com Jquery - realizado no lado do cliente

Faça que todos os buttons com a classe `btn` disparem um evento.

OBS: coloque ids nos inputs do primeiro formulario `txt_1` e `txt_2`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(e) {
        if($("#txt_1").val()== "" || $("#txt_2").val() ==""){

            //aqui você decide, pode ser um alerta, mudar a cor de fundo dos inputs, as bordas etc..
            alert('Campos vazios');  
            if($("#txt_1").val()== ""){
                $('#txt_1').css("background-color", "#FA8258");
            }else{
                $('#txt_1').css("background-color", "Aquamarine");
            }
            if($("#txt_2").val()== ""){
                $('#txt_2').css("background-color", "#FA8258");
            }else{
                $('#txt_2').css("background-color", "Aquamarine");
            }

            e.preventDefault();//evito o submit do form ao apertar o enter..    
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

**Exemplo completo** para quando retornar para o HTML, os dados preenchidos `NÃO sumirem` após o submit. Comentários no código

```
<?php
session_start();

//cria as sessions para preencher os values dos inputs no submit do form
if(isset($_POST['nome'])){
    $_SESSION['nome']=$_POST["nome"];
}
if(isset($_POST['cargo'])){
    $_SESSION['cargo']=$_POST["cargo"];
}

?>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(e) {
        if($("#txt_1").val()== "" || $("#txt_2").val() ==""){

            //aqui você decide, pode ser um alerta, mudar a cor de fundo dos inputs, as bordas etc..
            alert('Campos vazios');  
            if($("#txt_1").val()== ""){
                $('#txt_1').css("background-color", "#FA8258");
            }else{
                $('#txt_1').css("background-color", "Aquamarine");
            }
            if($("#txt_2").val()== ""){
                $('#txt_2').css("background-color", "#FA8258");
            }else{
                $('#txt_2').css("background-color", "Aquamarine");
            }

            e.preventDefault();//evitar o submit do form ao apertar o enter..    
            return false;
        }
    });

});
</script>

<!-- ##  Você deve usar o atributo value para definir o valor enviado pelos inputs e ao retornar preenche-lo com o valor da session ## -->

<form class="form-horizontal" id="FormInfObg" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="txt_1" value='<?php  echo $_SESSION['nome'] ?>' placeholder='Nome Completo'>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cargo" id="txt_2" value='<?php  echo $_SESSION['cargo'] ?>' placeholder='Cargo'>
    <button class="btn btn-default" name="btnSalvar" value="btnSalvar">Salvar <span class="fa fa-floppy-o"></span></button>
</form>

 <form class="form-horizontal" id="Form2" action="proc.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="filial">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="btnSubmitForm2">Enviar</button>
</form> 

<form class="form-horizontal" id="Form3" action="proc.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nSerial">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="btnSubmitForm3">Enviar</button>
</form>
```